# Change billing country Windows Live / Zune

Tags: zune, windows-live, windows-phone

When I registered my Live account, I had the country set to US - primarily because at the time I was going to explore getting a Zune pass. I never ended up getting it and now want to change my account to Australia so I can use my Australian credit card to purchase software from the market place.

Does anyone have any experience here in changing the billing country so I can use my Credit Card?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Did you end up creating a new account?

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo nope. I moved back to the iTunes ecosystem because Microsoft make simple things too difficult. Support requests were unanswered so just decided to leave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to like the answer, but from my research - there is currently no way to change your Zune billing country. The only option is to create a new Windows Live account.

I've tried this before since I've lived in both USA & Canada, but have been unsuccessful. Here are a few threads on the Microsoft forums with the same conclusion: [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/zune/forum/account-phone/change-country-after-relocating/b819b7bc-7d19-4db4-bd6b-bfb4ff6c43d0) and [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/zune/forum/account-phone/cannot-connect-to-windows-live-id-location-setting/26568fb8-ad63-49f2-ac6b-b24a5380444f#aa1e6b8d-3be7-4ec4-b195-4268fb80c9b3)

It's easy to change your Windows Live Account country of course (go to your Profile > Edit Details > Contact Info) - but that is not related to your Zune billing profile.

Comment: You'll need to contact the Live guys to get this fixed. Unfortunately, they're an elusive unhelpful team. Perhaps creating a thread at http://windowslivehelp.com/forums.aspx?productid=10 would help.

Comment: @Rafael thanks. Will look into it. @FrankieA - Thanks for your answer - I had guessed as much.